# Which wildcards can I use for a Microsoft Access form asking for month and year?

Tags: microsoft-access, database, database-administration

I made an Access Database that includes dates. I have a Report connected to a query that, when opened, prompts the user for a month in numbers (1-12) in order to produce the report for that months. For example, if I type 4, I get the report for April.
The problem is that sometimes I want a full report for all months and I beleive I need to type a wildcard in that field in order to get that. I have tried *, ?, #, %, "1-12" and "1,2,3...,12" but none worked, I just get an empty report.

Here is an image of the prompt:

[image]

Comment: How is the prompt generated? Is the prompt in the query or in the report? what happens if you leave it blank and click OK?

Comment: It is generated by writing [prompt] in the criteria field when creating the Query. Since the report comes from that Query, it also prompts the user for the same info. If you leave it blank y get a blank report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the prompt is coming of the criteria for the query itself, then you need to modify the query, not the report.

Using `Is Null` and `Is Not Null` in a new expression you can tell Access to either use the given criteria or return all records.

1. Copy your criteria and paste it in the top `Field` of a new column
   (*Note: you do not need to include the `Expr1:` seen in my example
   below. Access will add that for you.*)
2. Uncheck the `Show` box.
3. In the first criteria adjacent to your prompt, type `Is Not Null`.
4. Then in the `or` field below it type `Is Null`.

It should look something like this:

[image]

Now you can either enter a number or leave it blank. If you leave it blank, it will return all records found by the query.

Comment: I´m not sure how, but it works like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to help. It is simply checking the condition of the expression. If it there is data in the expression it uses that to filter your results. If there isn't any data in the expression (null) then it uses the `or` criteria which is not to filter out anything.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate report for "All months":

1. Duplicate the existing report.
2. In the new report, remove the prompt and filter.

Comment: Although this is a work around solution, I don't think it really answers the OP's question.

Comment: This might be a last option kind of answer. I hope someone can help me solve the problem without needing 2 reports.